# How to shift several buttons when mouse enter over another one

Tags: wpf, button, shift

How to shift several buttons when mouse enter

Please see this view:

[image]

Now what i want to add it's when the `mouse enter` over the Add `button` the Run button will shift to the right so i will see this view:

[image]

If it possible i want to see the shift takes not immediately but about 200-500 milliseconds.

There is a simple way to do that or i need to change the `margin` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the best way is the simplest way.

Here's an example:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
    <Button Content="Add" MouseEnter="AddButton_MouseEnter"/>
    <Button Name="btnItem1" Content="Item 1" Margin="3,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Button Name="btnItem2" Content="Item 1" Margin="3,0,0,0" Visibility="Collapsed"/>
    <Button Content="Run" Margin="3,0,0,0"/>
</StackPanel>
```

And here is the code-behind:

```
private async void AddButton_MouseEnter(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Delay(200);

    btnItem1.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    btnItem2.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
}
```

Comment: The question author requested that *the shift takes not immediately but about 200-500 milliseconds*.

Comment: @Sheridan, Wait, does he mean an animation?

Comment: It sounds like it, but that would entail a whole lot more work... perhaps he can complete that on his own and maybe add another question if he gets stuck with it?

Comment: Yes i mean animation, i want the other 2 button appears with animation

Comment: BTW i cannot click on the other 2 buttons cause after the mouse leave they disappear

Comment: @Sheridan Perhaps so, I doubt anyone would write the whole thing for him. If he tries *something* and gets stuck, then that's all good. OP, I have edited my answer, simply remove **MouseLeave**.

Comment: Yes but i want item1 and item2 buttons disappear in case the user didn't want to press on this buttons

Comment: @berrywer, the `MouseLeave` event occurs when the user's mouse leaves the `Button`, so even if the user went to click on one of the additional `Button`s, they would disappear before they could. You would have to add a similar delay into the event handler before hiding the `Button`s so that they would have time to click it.

Comment: But what to do if i want spaces between my button ? currently they stack for each other